# I am looking to cut off voltage from an LED when voltage drops below 1.7V

Tags: voltage, led, indicator

I have this indicator that will inform me with an LED when a switch goes bad. I am creating a test unit that will mimic the equipment. The equipment wont show a fault unless the switch leaks more than 1.7V. My goal is to mimic this as simple as possible(the equipment is full of integrated circuits that i can't dig into). I need something with a hard cut-off. Zener diodes haven't worked. I have also tried using a IRF9520 gate with a TL431, but that wont reach a low enough voltage.

Comment: Have you looked into TLV431?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get a sharp cutoff is to use a comparator, for example:

[image]

The LM311 will work with a supply up to 30VDC so you can use pretty much whatever supply you have available.

Pretty sharp:

[image]